# React/node app not booting due to "FieldArrayProps is not defined" after upgrading core

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sharetribe

I've just upgraded our customized sharetribe-flex code
(its a node/react app)

After resolving some merge conflicts, when starting app I get:

```
ReferenceError: FieldArrayProps is not defined
./node_modules/react-final-form-arrays/dist/react-final-form-arrays.es.js
node_modules/react-final-form-arrays/dist/react-final-form-arrays.es.js:294
  291 | _defineProperty(FieldArray, "displayName", "ReactFinalFormFieldArray(" + version$1 + ")(" + version + ")");
  292 | 
  293 | polyfill(FieldArray);
> 294 | var decorated = withReactFinalForm < FieldArrayProps > FieldArray;
  295 | 
  296 | //
  297 |
```

What are some things I can do to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downgrade react-final-form-arrays to version 2.0.1. Version 2.0.2 caused a breaking bug, see issue below:

https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form-arrays/issues/72.